# Ignore list indentation while centering an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a thousands of pages worth of HTML that I can't feasibly alter, so this fix needs to be CSS or js based.

I've got `.special` `p` tags that are sometimes inside lists (usually not). I need them to center based on page width and ignore the list indentation.

Example:

```
<style>
.special{
font-weight:bold;
text-align:center;
}

</style>
<body>
Here comes a list!
<ol>
<li>Blah</li>
    <p class="special">Incorrect</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Blah</li>
        <p class="special">Incorrect</p>
    </ul>
</ol>

<p class="special">Correct</p>

<ol start="2">
    <li>Blah</li>
</ol>
</body>
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/xa3sT/1/

The first .special element is inside a list, so it's tabbed in.  The third is outside, so it centers correctly.  I've tried a number of solutions to render the former as the latter, but they were all for li elements and/or required special css rules for the parent list element.  The LI only fixes didn't work for the p tag, and I'm hesitant to use the global ul,ol solutions because these are odd-ball cases and I don't want to risk altering the appearance of the broad variety of lists in these documents.

Further, as you probably noticed the second element is inside a list nested within the first.  I've seen examples of this too, so the size of the indent is going to inconsistent.  This makes setting a negative text-indent won't work either.

I can always do something like this:

```
    .special{
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;

}

ul .special, ol .special{
    text-indent:-2.5em;

}
ul ul .special, ol ul .special, ul ol .special, ol ol .special{
    text-indent:-5em;

}
ul ul ul .special, ol ul ul .special, ul ol ul .special, ol ol ul .special,
ul ul ol .special, ol ul ol .special, ul ol ol .special, ol ol ol .special{
    text-indent:-7.5em;

}
ul ul ul ul .special, ol ul ul ul .special, ul ol ul ul .special, ol ol ul ul .special,
ul ul ol ul .special, ol ul ol ul .special, ul ol ol ul .special, ol ol ol ul .special,
ul ul ul ol .special, ol ul ul ol .special, ul ol ul ol .special, ol ol ul ol .special,
ul ul ol ol .special, ol ul ol ol .special, ul ol ol ol .special, ol ol ol ol .special{
    text-indent:-10em;

}
ul ul ul ul ul .special, ol ul ul ul ul .special, ul ol ul ul ul .special, ol ol ul ul ul .special,
ul ul ol ul ul .special, ol ul ol ul ul .special, ul ol ol ul ul .special, ol ol ol ul ul .special,
ul ul ul ol ul .special, ol ul ul ol ul .special, ul ol ul ol ul .special, ol ol ul ol ul .special,
ul ul ol ol ul .special, ol ul ol ol ul .special, ul ol ol ol ul .special, ol ol ol ol ul .special,
ul ul ul ul ol .special, ol ul ul ul ol .special, ul ol ul ul ol .special, ol ol ul ul ol .special,
ul ul ol ul ol .special, ol ul ol ul ol .special, ul ol ol ul ol .special, ol ol ol ul ol .special,
ul ul ul ol ol .special, ol ul ul ol ol .special, ul ol ul ol ol .special, ol ol ul ol ol .special,
ul ul ol ol ol .special, ol ul ol ol ol .special, ul ol ol ol ol .special, ol ol ol ol ol .special{
    text-indent:-12.5em;

}
```

But surely there is a better way to disregard list indentation for a given element?

Edit:  Marc's solution SHOULD work, but for IE7 and, perhaps, some other peculiarities with these documents that I have not enumerated here, it doesn't work for this specific problem.

Temp Solution:

```
$( ".special" ).each(function(index) {
  var depth = $(this).parents('ul,ol').length * -2.5;
  $(this).css('text-indent',depth+"em");
});
```

Going forward I'll work on a script to fix the underlying html structure so this isn't necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: Well this is a .special css !

Comment: What if you simply add `padding: 0` to your `.special` class and then get rid of all the nested css nonsense?

Comment: Tried it, padding and margin styles do not seem to have any effect on the p tag's offset.

Comment: Too bad you can't edit that invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A jQuery approach - proof of concept

You could do something like this:

```css
var parentWidth = 500;
var idealLeft = 18;

$('p.special').offset({ left: idealLeft }).width(parentWidth);
```

You need to do take care of determining the width of the page and an ideal value for the left indentation.  However, that is not too hard.

The key is to first apply a common left offset to all `p.special` elements and then set a common width.

In this case, you don't have to touch the legacy CSS and risk breaking any of the pre-existing lists.

See demo at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/whR9z/)

Comment: I like it!  I was working out the jQuery to set the indent based on list level, but setting a fixed left value is much more efficient.

Comment: The clue that made it easy was that you wanted the p.specials to be centered with respect to the page, so I just ignored the lists from the start.

Comment: jQuery 1.x supports IE7 so the problem may be with the CSS, how is it breaking?

Comment: You might want to look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334664/cross-browser-issue-with-offset-jquery-function Also check for quirks mode (DOCTYPE) related issues.

Comment: The p tag vanishes until I resize the window.  Could be related to overall document structure / parent divs.  Could just be IE9's emulation of IE7.  Messed with it a bit, and I'm unsure.  However, this will suffice until IE7 is deemed too irritating to support:
 $( ".special" ).each(function(index) {
  var depth = $(this).parents('ul,ol').length * -2.5;
  $(this).css('text-indent',depth+"em");
 });

Meanwhile I'll look into a py script that can reliably detect and fix the invalid html structure so this is no longer necessary.

Comment: It sounds like IE7 is not playing nice with jQuery, almost like the DOM is not being reflowed properly. Maybe a native JavaScript solution would do the trick, but I am not if it is worth the effort. Good luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

Try [Alexs G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717214/aleks-g)'s solution not with your `.special` class, but `ol` tag. But then nested styles will all gone.

```
 .special{
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align:center;
            background: #d4d4d4;
    }

    ol {
        list-style-position:inside;
        padding:0;
    }
```