# .offset() returns null in ie 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have following code in my application

HTML:

```
<div class="sticky-anchor"></div>
```

JS:

```
var offsetValue =$('.sticky-anchor').offset();
```

the offsetValue is always null in ie8 ,code works well in other browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334664/cross-browser-issue-with-offset-jquery-function

Comment: i am using jQuery versiotn v1.7.1