# Popover on mapped areas

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have been searching for hours now how to show bootstrap popovers (or any other popover) on mapped areas.
The only solution I found is a dead link...
I have tried to make my own popovers, but it only works on Firefox because I use `offset()` to position them and it gives me differents values cross browser.

If we have for example the following code (from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)) :

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
     <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="#">
     <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="#">
     <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="#">
</map>
```

I would like a popover to show besides the area when hovered.

I would be glad if someone has an answer out there.

Comment: Suggesting libs is offtopic here

Comment: If you have code that you need help with, please show that code in a [mcve]. You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so. If you are asking for a library, that is specifically off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I add code to explain my problem. What is the problem with asking libraries ? Anyway, I am only asking for a solution, not specifically a library.

Comment: You should be ok using Bootstrap popovers with custom positions. As for the `offset()` problem check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334664/cross-browser-issue-with-offset-jquery-function

Comment: This solution for `offset()` does not work for me...